# How do I fix slow water flow in my refrigerator door dispenser?

Tags: refrigerator, water-pressure

It's an 11 year old Frigidaire FRS26ZPH side-by-side, and this year the water flow started slowing down. It has gotten slower and slower over time, to the point where it's taking over a minute to fill an 8oz cup. (The ice maker is working normally.)

- Good pressure comes out of the copper pipe when disconnected from the back of the unit.
- I have changed the water filter.
- I have defrosted the reservoir tank.

What else can effect the flow? My assumption is that this works solely off the house water pressure, or is there an interal pump involved?

Comment: When you say the ice maker works normally, is it re-filling quickly after dumping the ice?

Answer (score 3):

If the ice maker if refilling quickly after making a batch of ice, then the problem will likely be in the valve in the door dispenser or some kind of blockage in the line leading there.

The first easy fix that comes to mind is an ice buildup, since I've seen that wreck havoc on in door dispensers. You can try turning off the fridge and taking a hair dryer to the dispenser from each side to defrost any buildup, and then do your best to dry out anything that drips.

Beyond that, this will probably require taking the dispenser apart, possibly replacing the valve, or it may be as easy as cleaning the spout.